# Why does NavigationLink get activated each time I type a character into TextField in my SwiftUI Project?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have the following SwiftUI code, IngredientView struct, that activates the NavigationLink every time I type a character into the TextField.
[MySwiftUIProjectOnGitHub](https://github.com/sjlearmonth/Cocktail-Heaven)

```
struct IngredientView: View {
    
    @State var enteredIngredient: String = ""
    @State var ingredientIsEntered: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemTeal)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                Text("Please enter the ingredient you want to search for.")
                    .padding(50.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 20.0))
                    .navigationTitle("Search by Ingredient")
                
                TextField("Ingredient", text: $enteredIngredient)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(width: 250.0, height: 60.0, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(viewModel: ViewModel(urlString: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?i=\(enteredIngredient)", dataType: "Ingredients")), isActive: $ingredientIsEntered, label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    if !enteredIngredient.isEmpty
                    {
                        ingredientIsEntered = true
                    }
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Continue")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 25.0))
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 250.0)
                })
                    .background(.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30.0))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to my project repo on GitHub https://github.com/sjlearmonth/Cocktail-Heaven
Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I can do to stop it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you posted works for me, the `NavigationLink` does not activate 
when I type in the `TextField`. Note that, you create a new `ViewModel` 
every time you use the `NavigationLink`, this is probably not what you want.
You should have one `ViewModel` (one source of truth) in `IngredientView` that you pass to `DetailsView`.

Comment: @workingdog Thanks, did you download my project repo and run the app?

Comment: yes, tested both, the code above and the code from your repo. All works well for me on macos 12.1beta, Xcode 13.2 beta, target ios 15. Tested on real ios15 device.

Comment: @workingdog Are you sure it is working? That's really strange because I have just downloaded and run a fresh clone of my repo and it is still not working. The ViewModel structure keeps getting initialised every time I type a character.

Comment: your original issue does not happen for me, the NavigationLink does not activate when I type in the TextField.
Your "new" issue, "...The ViewModel structure keeps getting initialised every time I type a character."
As I mentioned before, you should have one ViewModel (one source of truth) 
that you pass to other views. Currently you create a new `ViewModel` every time you click 
on some link and change to `DetailsView`. This is the root of all your problems.
Read about `@StateObject, @ObservedObject, @EnvironmentObject` etc... and how to use 
them in your code to have one `ViewModel`.